# Not getting a flat histogram as given by histeq()

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I have this piece of Matlab code. Please help me diagnose the problem, why I am not getting a flat histogram of an equalized image as we get using histeq() function.

```
clc,clear
%Image Read
orig=imread('gun.jpg');
orig=rgb2gray(orig);
[r, c]=size(orig);

%Image Equlization using histeq() 
equal_he=histeq(orig);
imhist(equal_he);  

%Manually equalizing the image using HE algorithm%%
hist_orig=imhist(orig);   %Finding histogram
pdf_hist=hist_orig/numel(orig);   %Probability density histogram
cdf_hist=cumsum(pdf_hist);   %cumulative density histogram
%Finding Equalized image
equal(find(orig(orig<256)+1)) = 235*cdf_hist(orig(orig<256)+1);
equal=uint8(reshape(equal,r,c));
figure,imhist(equal);
```

This code gives me the following results

## Histogram of image obtained manually

[image: Histogram of image obtained manually]

## Histogram of image obtained using `histeq`

[image: Histogram of image obtained using histeq]

## Input image

[image: Input Image used for equalization]

## Reference to assertion about histogram equalization

[image]

[Reference to another paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB4r0.png)

Comment: (1) Histogram equalization does not give you an entirely flat histogram in practice.  In fact that image you posted is the best it'll ever give you. (2) By default, `histeq` uses only 64 bins.  Try bumping up the number of bins to 256 and see how it goes: `equal_he = histeq(orig, 256);`.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the help. Yes I am getting the same histogram now. There is another doubt though. It is said that that equalized image has mean = (min + max )/2 which doesnot happen to be in my case ( I checked for both images obtained using histeq and my own manual method respectively). Please guide. I have edited the question.

Comment: That's the first time I've ever heard of that assertion (i.e. `mean = (min + max) / 2`).  What reference are you referring to that makes that assertion?

Comment: This is the reference paper by Y.-T. Kim "Contrast Enhancement Using Brightness Preserving Bi-Histogram Equalization",1997, IEEE.

Comment: It says "Suppose that X is a continuous random variable, i.e.,
L = inf, then the output of the histogram equalization,
Y is also regarded as a random variable. It is
well known that the histogram equalization produces
an image whose gray levels have a uniform density,
i.e., `p(z) = l/(max - min)` , using which the author has claimed that `mean = (min + max) / 2`.

Comment: @NavdeepSony L is not infinite in this case. It is discrete, 256 levels?

Comment: @NavdeepSony That is a **theoretical** limit where there are an **infinite** number of bins.. i.e... it is continuous.  This histogram is **discrete** so there is no way to approach that limit unless you increase the number of bins towards infinity.  Histogram equalization has its uses other than in image enhancement.  It can be used for continuous processes and in that case, the assertion stated in the paper holds.  Because this is being applied to a discrete signal rather than continuous, this is why you will **never** achieve a truly "flat" histogram and it is only an approximation.

Comment: @rayryeng please check the reference given above.

Comment: @hiandbaii please check the reference given above.

Comment: @NavdeepSony That doesn't change what I said. You can stare at that reference link until you're blue in the face.  Also, it is the **expected value**... keyword.. **expected** in terms of probability (i.e. `E(Y)`).  This does **not** guarantee that you will see the mean value as `(min + max) / 2`.  Before we continue this discussion, I suggest you brush up on your probability theory concepts.  I don't think there's any more point in this discussion.

Comment: @rayryeng you mean to say that for an equalized image, the condition, `mean = (min + max) / 2)` and `p(z) = l/(max - min)` do not hold true?

Comment: @NavdeepSony only for a **continuous random variable**.  That's why the paper asserts that `L = inf`. This is **not the case**.  An image is a **discrete random variable**, assuming that all intensities are equiprobable.  This is my last message. Have fun.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks a lot for your help.It would have been better if I could have upvoted your answer but there is no option.

Comment: @NavdeepSony you're welcome.  If I formally wrote an answer, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @rayryeng I would like to accept your answer as I partially agree with you but I am still in doubt about whether `(min + max) / 2`and `p(z) = l/(max - min)` holds true only for continuous random variable and not for discrete random variable as the author has used these for discrete images and even used these to further prove his claim for bi-histogram equalization. Furthermore, I got another paper in which the other author has used these conditions for discrete variables. You can find in the second reference. Its my request to ponder once again and write a formal answer.

Comment: I'll leave it for someone else more equipped. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume a continuous random variable `X` with values inside the interval `0` and `255` and with size `512x512`, as mentioned in the paper, represented in this example as:

```
>> X = randi(256, 512, 512) - 1;
>> X = uint8(X);
```

If we show this random variable as an image we have:

```
>> imshow(X)
```

[image: Random variable X]

And if we check it's histogram, we can see that there's almost the same number of value for each intensity level and all the values in the range are filled with values. This way we can assume that our image had its histogram normalized:

```
>> figure , imhist(X, 256)
```

[image: Histogram]

For this particular case, we can say that our random variable `X` has a uniform density. So, `p(x) = 1 / (X_max - X_min)` means that for each intensity value the probability of occurrence is equal (but note that this is not true for our example, considering the slight difference between the number of values for each intensity level, anyway, it's pretty close).

```
>> X_max = 255;
>> X_min = 0;
>> p = 1/(X_max + X_min)
p =
    0.0039
```

If you plot the cumulative sum of the probabilities for each value you can see that this is pretty close:

```
>> figure , bar(p .* [0:255])
>> figure , bar(cumsum(imhist(X, 256)) ./ numel(X))
```

[image: CDFs]

Now that we know that our example case is very close to the ideal case, let's calculate the final equation:

*"It is easy to show that the mean brightness of the output image of the histogram equalization is the middle gray level."*

```
>> (X_min + X_max) / 2
ans =
  127.5000

>> mean(X(:))
ans =
  127.5381
```

As you can see, even having an image very close to an ideal situation (with a theoretical equal probability for each pixel value) the values are not identical but pretty close. So, this is why the equations show the derivation for continuous random variable and not discrete.

Hope this help you understand better your problem. Be sure to read again @rayryeng awesome comments on your question, they're very helpful and can lead you to an answer.

Comment: Great detective work. This is what I was trying to get the OP to understand but we seem to have a failure to communicate. +1.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng! I took some time to read carefully your comments, get some conclusions on my own and build a simple example :) Understanding images in the continuous domain can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks @Eliezer for such nice example and a very nice explanation and thanks rayryeng too as I am now able to understand what he meant to say. May be there was a communication gap or may be I was not able to interpret it properly. btw who downgraded my question. Is it wrong to ask such questions? I think being a newcomer here its going to be tough for me. Thanks.